# What is the purpose of the 'Synchronize' button in LiveCycle Workbench?

Tags: livecycle, workbench

In LiveCycle Workbench ES/ES2 there is a 'Synchronize' button as well as a 'Check Out' button that is available for all asset files and folders in the Applications View. What is the purpose of the 'Synchronize' button when the 'Check Out' button will automatically synchronize a resource with the server? What happens to a checked-out resource if I click on its 'Synchronize' button?

Answer (score 1):

The Synchronize button is to synchronize the local version with the version in the repository.
The checkout is to push your local version to the repository.

If you work in a multi-developer environment, you should always synchronize your applications and assets before you check them out, in order to ensure that you are always editing the latest version of the application or asset.

Comment: The other way around: "The checkout is to download a local version from the repository."

Comment: Yes, of course you're right! I need to re-read what I write at the least twice :)